# python location of elements in one numpy array with location of equal elements in another array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I need not just the values, but the locations of elements in one numpy array that also appear in a second numpy array, and I need the locations in that second array too.

Here's an example of the best I've been able to do:

```
>>> a=np.arange(0.,15.)
>>> a
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
        11.,  12.,  13.,  14.])
>>> b=np.arange(4.,8.,.5)
>>> b
array([ 4. ,  4.5,  5. ,  5.5,  6. ,  6.5,  7. ,  7.5])
>>> [ (i,j) for (i,alem) in enumerate(a) for (j,blem) in enumerate(b) if alem==blem]
[(4, 0), (5, 2), (6, 4), (7, 6)]
```

Anybody have anything faster, numpy specific, or more "pythonic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an O((n+k)log(n+k)) (the naive algorithm is O(nk)) solution with `np.unique`

```
uniq, inv = np.unique(np.r_[a, b], return_inverse=True)
map = -np.ones((len(uniq),), dtype=int)
map[inv[:len(a)]] = np.arange(len(a))
bina = map[inv[len(a):]]
inds_in_b = np.where(bina != -1)[0]
elements, inds_in_a = b[inds_in_b], bina[inds_in_b]
```

or you could simply sort `a` for O((n+k)log(k))

```
inds = np.argsort(a)
aso = a[inds]
bina = np.searchsorted(aso[:-1], b)
inds_in_b = np.where(b == aso[bina])[0]
elements, inds_in_a = b[inds_in_b], inds[bina[inds_in_b]]
```

Answer (score 3):

For sorted array `a`, here's another approach with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) making use of its optional argument - `side` set as `left` and `right` -

```
lidx = np.searchsorted(a,b,'left')
ridx = np.searchsorted(a,b,'right')
mask = lidx != ridx
out = lidx[mask], np.flatnonzero(mask)
       # for zipped o/p : zip(lidx[mask], np.flatnonzero(mask))
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def searchsorted_where(a,b):  # @Paul Panzer's soln
    inds = np.argsort(a)
    aso = a[inds]
    bina = np.searchsorted(aso[:-1], b)
    inds_in_b = np.where(b == aso[bina])[0]
    return b[inds_in_b], inds_in_b

def in1d_masking(a,b):  # @Psidom's soln
    logic = np.in1d(b, a)    
    return b[logic], np.where(logic)[0]

def searchsorted_twice(a,b): # Proposed in this post
    lidx = np.searchsorted(a,b,'left')
    ridx = np.searchsorted(a,b,'right')
    mask = lidx != ridx
    return lidx[mask], np.flatnonzero(mask)
```

Timings -

Case #1 (Using sample data from question and scaling it up) :

```
In [2]: a=np.arange(0.,15000.)
   ...: b=np.arange(4.,15000.,0.5)
   ...: 

In [3]: %timeit searchsorted_where(a,b)
   ...: %timeit in1d_masking(a,b)
   ...: %timeit searchsorted_twice(a,b)
   ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 721 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop
```

Case #2 (Same as case #1 with no. of elems in `b` comparatively lesser than in `a`) :

```
In [4]: a=np.arange(0.,15000.)
   ...: b=np.arange(4.,15000.,5)
   ...: 

In [5]: %timeit searchsorted_where(a,b)
   ...: %timeit in1d_masking(a,b)
   ...: %timeit searchsorted_twice(a,b)
   ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.4 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 428 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 128 µs per loop
```

Case #3 (and comparatively much lesser elems in `b`) :

```
In [6]: a=np.arange(0.,15000.)
   ...: b=np.arange(4.,15000.,10)
   ...: 

In [7]: %timeit searchsorted_where(a,b)
   ...: %timeit in1d_masking(a,b)
   ...: %timeit searchsorted_twice(a,b)
   ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.8 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 392 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.9 µs per loop
```

Comment: What happens if you cut the first two lines from mine? They are there in case `a` is not sorted, so under your test conditions they should go I think ;-)

Comment: @divakar  Dang!  Didn't mean to assign homework!  :)  Thanks very much for a very helpful and thoughtful answer.  Thanks to everyone for your answers, BTW.

Comment: Divakar I checked myself. Unsurprisingly, in the last condition my function spends 3/4 of its time `argsort`ing `arange(15000.)`. In the middle condition it is still almost 2/3. So, I must protest your methodology in the strongest possible terms ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer Sorry, didn't look into the details, my apologies, updated! :)

Comment: @bob.sacamento Updated the timings and seems like Paul's solution is the fastest one in all conditions. So, you might want to reconsider that accept thing :)

Comment: @divakar  Thanks for all your help.  I'm tempted to leave yours as the accepted since you've done so much work, but if you say so ....  Thanks again.

Comment: @Divakar no prob, I wouldn't have noticed myself if the results hadn't been so puzzling. Oh, and very sporting about the accept thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.in1d` to find out the elements of `b` also in `a`, logical indexing and `numpy.where` can get the elements and index correspondingly:

```
logic = np.in1d(b, a)    
list(zip(b[logic], np.where(logic)[0]))
# [(4.0, 0), (5.0, 2), (6.0, 4), (7.0, 6)]

b[logic], np.where(logic)[0]
# (array([ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.]), array([0, 2, 4, 6]))
```